# Convolution of difference between max and min

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

There are three random variables, x,y,z distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. They are Independently distributed.

The question I was trying to answer is the following:

What is the probability that $max(x,y,z)-min(x,y,z) \leq \frac{2}{3} $.

I am interested in solving this by first calculating the joint PDF of the LHS. However, I can't seem to replicate the results I've found online. Here is what I did:

I see that to get the PDF of the max, and min we simply follow the procedure in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114516/probability-density-function-of-maxx-y) and the expected value is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197299/expected-value-of-maximum-of-two-random-variables-from-uniform-distribution).

The PDF of the max is $f_{max}=3a^2$ and pdf of the min is $f_{min}=3a^2-6a+3$, where $a \in [0,1]$

The source at the bottom says that the convolution of the two is:

$f_{minmax} = 6(a-a^2)$

To be clear, I want to know how the convolution is attained because everybody seems to just do it very quickly and I don't see the approach. What I am doing is $\int_0^1 f_{max}(z-t)f_{min}(-t) dt $, but i'm pretty sure this isn't the right expression to get the answer.

To see the solutions and problem see [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/ARMLC_2016_7.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the volume in $x$, $y$, $z$ space:

[image: Max[x,y,z]-Min[x,y,z] < 2/3]

Integrate the region's volume to find that the probability is $20/27$.

Comment: This is fun but I was asking how we get the expression for the convolution!

Comment: What does convolution have to do with anything here?

Comment: I can't figure how to @ you. Quite simply, the max and the min follow a distribution each, and then their difference is a convolution. The last link I have in my post shows an answer that claims the convolution is the $f_{minmax}$